# Rename the pdf file inside sub-directories to the name of the sub directory

Tags: batch-file, rename, subdirectory

I am using win 7 platform. Need your help to create a bat file which simplifies my job. My folders and files are arranged in this structure.

**File1**

- folder1
  ->abcd.pdf
- folder2
  ->shhd.pdf..............................
  folderN
  ->gfdfgd.pdf

**File2**

- folder1
  ->gbg.pdf
- folder2
  ->kjc67z.pdf..............................
  folderN
  ->iuxz4i.pdf

### --

### --

### --

**FileN**

- folder1
  ->ah455.pdf
- folder2
  ->jfhd45.pdf..............................
  folderN
  ->juvxzr.pdf

I want to generate a batch file which renames the pdf file to name of the folder it contains. For example, in the above structure "abcd.pdf" is renamed to folder1.pdf. Respectively this is done for all pdf files.

Also a folder named "test" is created inside each directory(file1,file2..etc) which contains all the renamed pdf files of its respective directory.

If i copy all the folders inside **File1** to Myfolder & run the bat file, a folder named test will be created and all the pdf file will be renamed and copied to test folder.

But what I want is, I want to run the bat file in H:\ drive. Lets assume H:\ drive contains all the directories File1, File2....FileN with each directory containing a sub-directory as I had shown in the above structure. If i run the bat file in H:\ drive, then a folder named **test** has to be created inside each directory which contains the renamed pdf files of its respective sub-directories.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Syon: I have edited my question and have added the code which i implemented. Please refer to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /a-d *.pdf') do (
     set "fname=%%~fa"
     for %%b in ("%%~dpa.") do set "nname=%%~nxb"
     setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
     ECHO ren "!fname!" "!nname!.pdf"
     endlocal
)
```

Note: you can rename only one pdf/folder.

---

Some other code for the OP:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
MKDIR "H:\Myfolder\test"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('DIR /b /a-d "H:\Myfolder"') do (
    ECHO %%i
    CD "H:\Myfolder\%%~i"
    ren *.pdf "%%~nxi.pdf"
    copy *.pdf "H:\Myfolder\test"
    cd H:\Myfolder
)
cd H:\Myfolder\test
del H:\Myfolder\test\test.pdf
```

Comment: Hi Endoro. I have now included the batch script which i implemented, in my question. Please refer it and let me know how can i improve it to fulfill my needs. Thanks

Comment: Endoro, can you please help me on how to create a **test** file inside each directory file1, file2....fileN which contains all the renamed pdf files of that respective sub-directories.

Comment: I tested it on the same folder structure. `not working`  is a poor error description.

Comment: I think i am nearing the answer. Can you please help me on creating a batch script which on running will move to File1 and then call my script and then move to File2 and call my script and so on.